# How create aggregate function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

how create agggregate function in PostgreSQL ?

I have a query that executes the code below, where I take the sum of two multiplied numbers. But I need an aggregate function to do this, and I've already done it like `select agg(vol,pri) from F`

```
select sum(Volume*Price) from F
```

Comment: "But I need an aggregate function" -- `sum()` is one...

Comment: @stickybit I know, but I need my own aggregate function  that will include sum(Volume*Price)

Comment: @stickybit So that I pass two parameters to it, and they are already multiplied and summed up there

Comment: If `sum()` apparently already can do what you want, why?

Comment: @stickybit I have a task to implement my own. So that I can learn and understand.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Then you might start by reading [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html) and try something. If that fails include the relevant code and what the exact problem is.

Comment: @stickybit I looked, but can't figure out what the argument means like: sfunc or stype and etc

Comment: Also check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html.  sfunc apparently means "state transition function"